# Find and delete data in firebase

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to delete a collection from a firebase after searching it based on id. This is the format of my data,

[image]

I want to delete the "request" (marked by red), after first searching it by the id (in this case id=1).
How do I go about this?

I am using firebase library in react native after installing it using npm.

Comment: Relevant reading: [Array Best Practices in Firebase RTDB](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To delete a node, you need to know the full path to that node. Since you only know a (unique) value in a property in that node, you can first run a query to determine the nodes with that value.

So something like:

```
let query = db.child("requests").orderByChild("id").equalTo(1);
query.once("value").then((snapshot) => {
  snapshot.forEach((child) => {
    child.ref.remove();
  })
});
```